# Add column for percentage of a total in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, percentage

I am trying to figure out a way to add a column that has a percentage of a total based on information of the column. I think it's possible but I just can't grasp the way to do it.

Here is a simplified version of my SQL code (which works fine) and table result:

```
select week
, restaurant
, case
    when cast(timestamp as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '03:00:01' and '10:00:00' then 'Breakfast'
    when cast(timestamp as time format 'HH:MI:SS') between '10:00:01' and '14:59:00' then 'Lunch'
    else 'Dinner'
    end
    as meal
, sum(revenue) as total_rev
, sum(case when product_type = 'food' then revenue else 0 end) as food_rev
, sum(case when product_type = 'bev' then revenue else 0 end) bev_rev

from table1
group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2,3
```

Table output

```
week  restaurant  meal       total_rev  food_rev  bev_rev
1     Taco Bell   Breakfast  300        200       100
1     Taco Bell   Lunch      250        210       40
1     Taco Bell   Dinner     450        250       200
1     McDonalds   Breakfast  100        70        30
1     McDonalds   Lunch      150        100       50
1     McDonalds   Dinner     250        130       120
2     Taco Bell   Breakfast  200        120       80
2     Taco Bell   Lunch      150        110       40
2     Taco Bell   Dinner     350        240       110
2     McDonalds   Breakfast  200        70        130
2     McDonalds   Lunch      250        120       130
2     McDonalds   Dinner     150        100       50
```

What I would like to do is create two additional columns to % of revenue per meal period for food and beverage for that week and restaurant.

So for example, week one for taco bell would have the percentage of food for breakfast as .3030 (200 / (200 + 210 + 250). And so on.

```
week  restaurant  meal       total_rev  food_rev per_food  bev_rev per_bev
1     Taco Bell   Breakfast  300        200      .3030     100     .2941
1     Taco Bell   Lunch      250        210      .3182     40      .1176
1     Taco Bell   Dinner     450        250      .3788     200     .5882
1     McDonalds   Breakfast  100        70                 30
1     McDonalds   Lunch      150        100                50
1     McDonalds   Dinner     250        130                120
2     Taco Bell   Breakfast  200        120                80
2     Taco Bell   Lunch      150        110                40
2     Taco Bell   Dinner     350        240                110
2     McDonalds   Breakfast  200        70                 130
2     McDonalds   Lunch      250        120                130
2     McDonalds   Dinner     150        100                50
```

Answer (score 5):

You can utilize a Group Sum to get the sum per week/restaurant like this:

```
100.00 * food_rev / sum(food_rev) over (partition by week restaurant)
```